# Update nested array by matching _id in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

> I want to update donation links by matching _id in events array, I am using embedded data model.  Also I want to find events using _id. I know how to do it with aggregate but I want to do it with finOne or find. I tried elemMatch method mentioned in mongo docs but that do not works.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("615db3ea27d50d4105e7439d"), 
    "covers" : [
        "https://inmemoryofyou-app-test.s3.amazonaws.com/funeral-home-images/e04d9e74-04f5-4cc0-9614-ef0da23a471d.jpeg"
    ], 
    "funeralHomeAdmins" : [
        "615db3e327d50db603e74399"
    ], 
    "name" : "Test", 
    "about" : "This is a funeral home", 
    "website" : "www.google.com", 
    "email" : "ankur4736@gmail.com", 
    "phone" : "9999999999", 
    "rootAdmin" : "615db3bb27d50d3597e7438e", 
    "logo" : "https://inmemoryofyou-app-test.s3.amazonaws.com/funeral-home-images/3c7d53c4-6cf9-4dfa-9ea9-a5244356b6dd.jpeg", 
    "events" : [
        {
            "eventAdmins" : [
                ObjectId("615db3e327d50db603e74399")
            ], 
            "donationLinks" : [
                ""
            ], 
            "created_at" : ISODate("2021-10-06T14:32:31.168+0000"), 
            "_id" : ObjectId("615db4a127d50d43bee743ab"), 
            "name" : "Events", 
            "location" : "Los Santos", 
            "description" : "This is an event", 
            "birthDate" : ISODate("2000-06-14T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "deathDate" : ISODate("2000-01-21T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "adminEmail" : "test@test.com", 
            "eventType" : "public", 
            "deceasedImg" : "https://inmemoryofyou-app-test.s3.amazonaws.com/event-images/07f178bb-de27-49e7-8a4a-84d1681f5a7b.jpeg"
        }, 
        {
            "eventAdmins" : [
                ObjectId("615db3e327d50db603e74399")
            ], 
            "donationLinks" : [
                "www.google.com"
            ], 
            "created_at" : ISODate("2021-10-06T14:32:31.168+0000"), 
            "_id" : ObjectId("615db4c127d50d987ce743b1"), 
            "name" : "Event with donation links", 
            "location" : "Los Santos", 
            "description" : "This is an event", 
            "birthDate" : ISODate("2016-06-07T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
            "deathDate" : ISODate("2021-10-04T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
            "adminEmail" : "test@test.com", 
            "eventType" : "public", 
            "deceasedImg" : "https://inmemoryofyou-app-test.s3.amazonaws.com/event-images/e8db4729-a31b-47ec-a0dc-fbd48b8c6bae.jpeg"
        }
    ], 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-10-06T14:34:18.978+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-10-08T08:55:03.015+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Comment: find is for finding documents not changing them,maybe you meanted updateOne? you can use aggregte pipeline on update also if it worked

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 possible solutions, choose one which better suits your needs.

**Method-1: Using `$set` with `$` selection**

Use this method if the `_id` key inside the `events` array of objects will be unique and you want to completely replace the `donationLinks` value.

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("615db3ea27d50d4105e7439d"),
  "events._id": ObjectId("615db4a127d50d43bee743ab"),
  
},
{
  "$set": {
    "events.$.donationLinks": [
      "Hi"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q_Upiy5fhge)

**Method-2: Using `$push` with `$` selection**

Use this method if the `_id` key inside the `events` array of objects will be unique and you want to append a value to the array instead

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("615db3ea27d50d4105e7439d"),
  "events._id": ObjectId("615db4a127d50d43bee743ab"),
  
},
{
  "$push": {
    "events.$.donationLinks": "Hi"
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MrYfdLs_Iuj)

**Method-3: Using `arrayFilters` with `$set` ot `$push`**

Use this method if there can be duplicates of the same `_id` key value inside the events array.

***Note:*** Use `$set`, `$push` or `$addToSet` as per your needs.

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("615db3ea27d50d4105e7439d"),
},
{
  "$push": {
    "events.$[elem].donationLinks": [
      "Hi"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem._id": ObjectId("615db4a127d50d43bee743ab"),
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FVbMFjRHo2f)

Comment: Can you also help me writing findOne for matching _id in events array

Comment: FuneralHomesModel.findOne(
            {
                'events._id': Types.ObjectId(event_id)
            }
        )

I tried this but its returning everything in array

Comment: I want to find match with just event id

Comment: Have a look at `$elemMatch` in MongoDB documentation. The answer required is outside the scope of this question. Post another question with the required output if you are not able to figure it out and I will be happy to help.